# Payment Request API: What is the Payee Account?

Tags: payment-processing, android-pay, payment-request-api

I was looking at the Payment Request API which is apparently available on some browsers but I was wondering, where/how do you set the account to which the payments get sent?  I see nowhere in the following code that specifies an account to which the payment will be sent upon success:

```
function onBuyClicked() {
  if (!window.PaymentRequest) {
    // PaymentRequest API is not available. Forwarding to
    // legacy form based experience.
    location.href = '/checkout';
    return;
  }

  // Supported payment methods
  var supportedInstruments = [{
      supportedMethods: ['basic-card']
      data: {
        supportedNetworks: [
          'visa', 'mastercard', 'amex', 'discover',
          'diners', 'jcb', 'unionpay'
        ]
      }
  }];

  // Checkout details
  var details = {
    displayItems: [{
      label: 'Original donation amount',
      amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '65.00' }
    }, {
      label: 'Friends and family discount',
      amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '-10.00' }
    }],
    total: {
      label: 'Total due',
      amount: { currency: 'USD', value : '55.00' }
    }
  };

  // 1. Create a `PaymentRequest` instance
  var request = new PaymentRequest(supportedInstruments, details);

  // 2. Show the native UI with `.show()`
  request.show()
  // 3. Process the payment
  .then(result => {
    // POST the payment information to the server
    return fetch('/pay', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(result.toJSON())
    }).then(response => {
      // 4. Display payment results
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // Payment successful
        return result.complete('success');
      } else {
        // Payment failure
        return result.complete('fail');
      }
    }).catch(() => {
      return result.complete('fail');
    });
  });
}

document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', onBuyClicked);
```

Ref. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/discovery-and-monetization/payment-request/deep-dive-into-payment-request

Ref. https://www.w3.org/TR/payment-request/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: you don't.

Payment Request API is *not* a replacement for payment processors. The browser itself has no means to process the funds transfer to your account - it can't even validate whether the provided payment method is valid (though Android Pay can do this).

Per [Introducing the Payment Request API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/discovery-and-monetization/payment-request/) doc (emphasis mine):

> ...
>
> The browser then presents the payments UI to the user, who selects a
>   payment method and authorizes the transaction. A payment method can be
>   as straightforward as a credit card that is already stored by the
>   browser, or as esoteric as third-party application written
>   specifically to deliver payments to the site (this functionality is
>   coming soon). After the user authorizes the transaction, **all the
>   necessary payment details are sent directly back to the site**. For
>   example, for a credit card payment, **the site will get back a card
>   number, a cardholder name, an expiration date, and a CVC**.
>
> ...

In other words, the Payment Request API is just an easier, safer way for you to collect the user's card number and other info necessary to process a payment. Once you receive this information, it's pretty much the same as if the user submitted it via a normal form. You still need a payment processor (or something similar) to actually create a transaction.